# Consuming message from ActiveMQ and Publishing to Azure Service Bus Topic

Tags: spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic, azureservicebus

I have a requirement to consume JMS message from ActiveMQ queue and publish it to Azure Service Bus Topic. I have used Spring Boot for this project and using Apache qpid to connect Service Bus over AMQP protocol.

The problem I am facing is, after consuming message from ActiveMQ during publishing message to Service Bus Topic if for any reason exception occur I am not able to retain message in ActiveMQ. I want ActiveMQ to hold message until I am able to publish message in Service Bus. I tried using acknowledgement as Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE in listener container factory but somewhere from exception it is returning as success which cause ActiveMQ to drop message. However ActiveMQ is able to retry sending 7 time but after that it just drop message.

Below is my code detail.
I to have to use 2 configuration class to connect ActiveMQ and Service Bus which are as below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class RecevierConfig {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RecevierConfig.class);

    @Value("${activemq.host}")
    private String activemqHost;

    @Value("${activemq.protocol}")
    private String activemqProtocol;

    @Value("${activemq.port}")
    private String activemqPort;

      @Bean
      public ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        logger.info("Broker URL : "+activemqProtocol+"://"+activemqHost+":"+activemqPort);
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(activemqProtocol+"://"+activemqHost+":"+activemqPort);

        return activeMQConnectionFactory;
      }

      @Bean
      public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency("3-10");
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        factory.setErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler());
        return factory;

      }

      @Bean
      public QueueReceiver receiver() {
        return new QueueReceiver();
      }

}
```

Below is to create ConnectionFactory and jmsTemplate for Service Bus connection to publish message.

```
@Configuration
public class MessagingConfig {

      @Value("${spring.application.name}")
        private String clientId;


        @Bean
        @Primary
        public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory(MessageStoreDetails details) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
            JmsConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory = new JmsConnectionFactory(details.getSBUrlString());
            jmsConnectionFactory.setUsername(details.getUsername());
            jmsConnectionFactory.setPassword(details.getPassword());
            jmsConnectionFactory.setClientID(clientId);
           // jmsConnectionFactory.setReceiveLocalOnly(true);
            return new CachingConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory);
        }

        @Bean
        public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory) {
            JmsTemplate returnValue = new JmsTemplate();
            returnValue.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory);
            return returnValue;
        }

}
```

Below is the code for QueueReceiver receiving message from ActiveMQ

```
@Service
public class QueueReceiver {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QueueReceiver.class);

    @Autowired
    private TopicPublisher topicPublisher;

    @JmsListener(destination = "${activemq.queue}")
    public void receiveMessage(Message message) {

        try {
            logger.info("*****Received message from ActiveMQ queue : " + message.getJMSMessageID());
            topicPublisher.sendMessage(message);
            message.acknowledge();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //logger.error(e.toString());
            throw new MessageProcessingException(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Finally below is the class to publish message

```
@Service
public class TopicPublisher {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TopicPublisher.class);

    @Value("${servicebus.topic}")
    private String topic;

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public void sendMessage(javax.jms.Message message) throws Exception {
           logger.info("#### Sending message to Service Bus Topic : "+ topic +" Message ID: "+ message.getJMSMessageID());
           jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(topic, message);
           logger.info("**** Message Sent to Service Bus Topic : "+ topic +" Message ID: "+ message.getJMSMessageID());
    }

}
```

Comment: can you try and push the message on some DLQ when exception occurs? then try and listen to DLQ, your message is lost because if your `receiveMessage()` function executes completely then ActiveMQ considers the message as delivered.

Comment: Thanks Vihar. I was able to push message to DLQ. However after reading about Apache Camel I think it is best option to use Camel in this case to get message from ActiveMQ and publish to Service Bus. Currently exploring that option. Wondering how can I config multiple endpoint in connection factory. Do you have any reference from where I can get code example using Camel and multiple JMS provider ?